# Combine duplicate rows depends on 2 columns values in laravel 8

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have this table 'day_meals':

| id | user_id | meal_id | meal_variable_id | date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 7 | 1 | 1 | 2022-07-13 |
| 2 | 7 | 5 | 1 | 2022-07-13 |
| 3 | 7 | 7 | 7 | 2022-07-13 |
| 4 | 7 | 7 | 7 | 2022-07-13 |
| 5 | 7 | 9 | 9 | 2022-07-13 |
| 6 | 7 | 6 | 1 | 2022-07-13 |

I am trying to get all records in the same date and combine duplicate row who have the same meal_id and meal_variable_id

so here we have 6 rows i want to get 5 rows and the rows (3, 4) combined with count = 2

i tried this code:

```php
$meals_day = DayMeal::where('date', date('Y-m-d'))->get();
$data = collect($meals_day)->groupBy(['meal_id', 'meal_variable_id']);
```

and this one:

```php
$meals_day = DayMeal::where('date', date('Y-m-d'))
    ->get()
    ->groupBy(['meal_id', 'meal_variable_id']);
```

but this code return 5 rows without the the quantity:

```
Illuminate\Support\Collection {#1409 ▼
  #items: array:5 [▼
    1 => Illuminate\Support\Collection {#1445 ▼
      #items: array:1 [▶]
      #escapeWhenCastingToString: false
    }
    5 => Illuminate\Support\Collection {#1447 ▼
      #items: array:1 [▶]
      #escapeWhenCastingToString: false
    }
    7 => Illuminate\Support\Collection {#1449 ▼
      #items: array:1 [▶]
      #escapeWhenCastingToString: false
    }
    9 => Illuminate\Support\Collection {#1451 ▼
      #items: array:1 [▶]
      #escapeWhenCastingToString: false
    }
    6 => Illuminate\Support\Collection {#1453 ▼
      #items: array:1 [▶]
      #escapeWhenCastingToString: false
    }
  ]
  #escapeWhenCastingToString: false
}
```

how can I get 5 rows and with quantity for duplicated rows depending on 2 columns (`meal_id` and `meal_variable_id`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using collection group by, i would instead utilize `SQL`, which is a little less convenient but more powerful.

```
DayMeal::where('date', now()->format('Y-m-d'))
    ->groupBy(['meal_id', 'meal_variable_id', 'date'])
    ->select('meal_id', 'meal_variable_id', 'date', DB::raw('count(id)'))
    ->get();
```

Notice, not using `get()` or `first()` to execute the query, before the last step, which is different from your approach. Depending if you run your `SQL` in strict mode, you can have trouble selecting columns which are not aggregate or in the group by. Which can make your models not contain columns, not in the select statement.